# SQL Cursor to generate unique non sequencial PINS

Tags: sql-server, loops, random, cursor, unique

I am trying to generate non sequential unique PINS for bunch of new employees. 
Here is how it should work:

1. A cursor should fetch all the new employees from table B
2. Generate new unique pins for each new employee
3. Check if the newly generated PIN already exists in Table A
4. If yes, repeat step 2 until we get unique PIN for all the new employees
5. Insert the new employee number and PINs into Table A

On table A the fields are PIN, Employee_Number, Date

I tried to use cursor to insert each new emp and his PIN one by one, so that it checks for uniqueness at each insert:

This only loops once and stops, can someone tell me what I am missing

```
 DECLARE 
    @EmpNo             VARCHAR(50), 
    @Pin               INT, 
    @today             DATETIME,
    @Upper             INT,
    @Lower             INT,
SET @Lower = 100000 ---- The lowest random number allowed
SET @Upper = 999999 ---- The highest random number allowed

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 

SELECT   
       Employee_Number, 
       (ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0))as PIN, 
       GETDATE()
FROM     TableB 
WHERE    Employee_Number NOT IN (SELECT Employee_Number FROM TableA)


OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @EmpNo, @Pin, @Today

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

BEGIN    

         INSERT INTO TableA (PIN, Employee_Number, Date)
         SELECT @Pin, @EmpNo, @Today


FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Pin, @EmpNo, @Today
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need cursor. Also it is better to use newid() to generate the random number instead of rand()

```
INSERT INTO TableA (PIN, Employee_Number, Date)
SELECT pin = @Lower 
           + (   abs(convert(bigint,convert(varbinary(20),newid()))) 
               % (@Upper - @Lower + 1) 
             ),
       Employee_Number,
       GETDATE()
FROM   TableB 
WHERE  Employee_Number NOT IN (SELECT Employee_Number FROM TableA)
```

EDIT :

to handle unique pin, the solution without using cursor is to keep a table of all possible pin.

```
create table pin
(
    pin         int primary key,
    is_used     bit default 0
)
```

you generate the pin using recursive cte

```
; with num as
(
    -- anchor member
    select  pin = @Lower

    union all

    -- recursive member
    select  pin = pin + 1
    from    num
    where   pin < @Upper
)
insert into pin (pin) 
select  pin
from    num
```

then when you need to assign the pin to the employee

```
; with emp as
(
    select  Employee_Number, rn = row_number() over (order by Employee_Number)
    from    TableA a
    where   not exists
            (
                select  *
                from    TableB b
                where   b.Employee_Number   = a.Employee_Number
            )
),
pin as
(
    -- get unused pin, order it randomly using newid()
    select  pin, rn = row_number() over (order by newid())
    from    pin
    where   is_used = 0
)
insert into #TableB (Employee_Number, pin)
select  e.Employee_Number, p.pin
from    emp e
        inner join pin p    on  e.rn    = p.rn
```

after that update is_used column in pin table

```
update  p
set     is_used = 1
from    TableB b
        inner join #pin p   on  b.pin   = p.pin
where   p.is_used   = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. This query works without generating any duplicate PIN, however throws UNIQUE KEY constraint error as the pin field on table a is made UNIQUE. Will it be safe to remove this unique key feature from the pin field?

Comment: And also while inserting, the query should also check table A any repeated pins

Comment: Why the PIN must be unique across employee ? does not really make sense to me

Comment: unique pin will complicate the query. However, to insure unique pin, you may consider use IDENTITY in the pin column.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed, isn't that will make the PIN `sequential` ?

Comment: IDENTITY alone will make it sequential, but you may concatenate or embid  it with your random number to form unique code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be as follows.

Note @EmpTable is a demonstrative EmpTable (Remove @ for your environment)

1) cte0 generates a base tally table of 10 rows

2) cteR expands cte0 to 1,000 rows and adds a random string (NewID())

3) cteI converts cteR into an INT (no more than 6 digits)

4) Update is applies to all NULL PINS

```
Declare @EmpTable table (Employee_Number int,PIN int)
Insert Into @EmpTable values
(1,100288),(2,651701),(3,823700),
(4,NULL),(5,NULL)

Declare @Lower int=100000,@Upper int = 999999

 ;with cte0(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
     , cteR(R)   As (Select Distinct R=cast(NewID() as varchar(50)) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4) 
     , cteI(R,N) As (Select Distinct R,cast(Left(cast(abs(cast(Hashbytes('MD5',R) as int)) as varchar(25)),6) as int) From cteR R) 
Update @EmpTable Set PIN = B.N
 From  @EmpTable A
 Join  (
         Select RowNr=(Select min(Employee_Number)-1 From @EmpTable Where PIN is NULL)+Row_Number() over (Order By R)
               ,N 
          From  cteI 
          Where N Between @Lower and @Upper
            and N not in (Select Distinct PIN From @EmpTable Where PIN is not NULL)
        ) B on A.Employee_Number=B.RowNr and PIN is null


Select * from @EmpTable
```

Updated EmpTable

```
Employee_Number PIN
1               100288   -- Same as Original
2               651701   -- Same as Original
3               823700   -- Same as Original
4               118844   -- New Random PIN
5               677855   -- New Random PIN
```